# Button above a carousel does not align center

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Let me show first the issue just to visualize it (i just hid the logo)

[image]

as you can see the button does not align with the logo, which is in the center. behind them is a carousel.

```css
.logo-front {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50%;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 35%;
  left: 25%;
}

.button-front {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50%;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 55%;
  color: white !important;
  border: 2px solid white !important;
  max-width: 250px;
  margin: 30 !important;
}

.button-front:hover {
  border: 2px solid #d8b861 !important;
}

.logo-front-sm {
  position: absolute;
  width: 40%;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 15%;
  left: 30%;
}
```

```html
<ul class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ul>

    <div class="carousel-inner">

        <img class="logo-front" src="img/logo/logo_2.png">

        <a href="properties-for-lease.php">
          <button type="submit" class="site-button button-front">LEARN MORE</button>
        </a>

      <div class="carousel-item active">
        <img src="img/slider/slider1.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img src="img/slider/slider2.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img src="img/slider/slider3.jpg">
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

in the button-front i tried "margin: 0 auto;" and "text-align: center;" but the button still stays in the side.

Comment: check my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e82c6hrz/)

Comment: please create a fiddle for this

Comment: Also don't use `!important` if it's not necessary

Comment: images are not loading in fiddle.

Comment: @user3260487 ofcourse... because the images are local... and it doesn't matter as long as the button works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You used your width wrong. You forgot % or px. And you have to use `top:` to define the height. So that is what i changed here [**fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/e82c6hrz/)